# Vue.js unit testing updating vuex store error

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-test-utils

I am changing vuex state value using commit in my tests and then trying to see whether element that supposed to be rendered based on the change is present.
Something like this

```
it('should render error state if no stores', () => {
    wrapper.store.commit('stores/updateLoadingStores', false);
    wrapper.store.commit('stores/updateStores', []);
    expect(wrapper.find('error-state-stub').exists()).toBe(true);
});
```

Instead I am getting next error
    ```
    StoresStep › should render error state if no stores

````
TypeError: Cannot read property '_isDestroyed' of undefined

  31 |     const mutationName = `${prefix}${_upperFirst(name)}`;
  32 |     acc[mutationName] = (state, value) => {
> 33 |       state[name] = value;
     |       ^
  34 |     };
  35 |     return acc;
  36 |   }, {});

  at destroy (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:3151:28)
  at invokeDestroyHook (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:6088:59)
 ...
```
````

The function it complains about is a wrapper to set value to specific module.
See actual error - `TypeError: Cannot read property '_isDestroyed' of undefined`
which is coming from `vue.runtime.common.dev.js`

I thought it is Vue.$nextTick() related but seems like no.

`wrapper.store` part is just util I wrote to be able to mount component and use everything related to it in one place.

Will appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you provide code of `wrapper` creating?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I figured it out. The problem was not obvious. I had to dig through vue.js source code to find a clue to the original issue. Basically, this vue-test-utils issue partially explains it - https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/issues/52

The biggest problem was that error doesn't link you to transitions at all, so I was looking in the wrong direction.

And the solution is simple, just stub transition :)

```
VueTestUtils.config.stubs['transition'] = true;
```